# CSS Float overflow

Tags: html, css

I have this sample html

```
 <html>
     <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .div-menu
            {
                width:300px;
                margin-left:20px;
                margin-right:20px; 
                float:left;
                border:thin solid;      
                min-height:600px;
                height:auto;
            }

            .div-content
            {
                float:left;
                min-width:700px;
                width:auto;
                border:thin solid;         
                min-height:600px;
                height:auto;          
                padding-right:20px;
            }   
        </style>
     </head>

     <body>
        <div style="margin-top:50px;padding:10px;">
            <div class="div-menu">

            </div>


            <div class="div-content">
                <div id='main' style="width:2000px;background-color:lightblue;height:600px">
                    Hello world

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


     </body>

     </html>
```

when the div main have actual width that larger than page width , the div-contain is break down to the bottom of div-menu , i want to make that div keep by side of div-menu , and the window horizontal scrollbar will appear ,

how can i achieve

Appreciate any suggest

thank

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
<div style="margin-top:50px;padding:10px;">
```

to

```
<div style="width:2364px; margin-top:50px;padding:10px;">
```

specify a width equal to the sum of the effective widths of div-menu and div-content

In this case the width should be 2364px

This is calculated by finding the sum of div_width + margin_widths + padding_widths + border_widths

(300+20+20+2)+(2000+20+2)=2364

Comment: but the div main is dynamic content which we can not predicate the size of, if width of main less than the top-div (width=2400 as you suggest) , the layout will have a unnecessary white space , look confused !

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain `width` and height of the `parent DIV` according to content inside it.
Check this [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) to maintain this.

If parent have width 600px  then  width or height of inner div's  should be

> Inner Div actual width/height + border width + padding <= 600

So Specify some width to your parent div as per your requirement( 1024px is standard width nowadays)  as:

```
<div style="width:1024px; margin-top:50px;padding:10px;">
```

then read about the box model and maintain your inner Div width/height.

If there width is not defined then use [css overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) and a simple tutorial available [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=scroll).

for example your content div have not prediction about width/height then use `overflow`

```
div
{
overflow:scroll;
}
```

In CSS3, you can specify in which direction you want to manage:
check these
[CSS OVERFLOW-X](http://www.css3.com/css-overflow-x/)

example:

```
blockquote { width: 50px; height: 50px; overflow-x: scroll }

<blockquote style=”width: 50px; height: 50px; overflow-x: scroll”>some text</blockquote>
```

[CSS OVERFLOW-Y](http://www.css3.com/css-overflow-y/)